# Remove duplicate values from the end of an array

Tags: php, arrays

Many questions answer how to remove dublicate values of an array, but how do you remove duplicate values from the **end** of an array? For example an array with these values:

```
28, 56, 26, 369, 114, 26, 26, 26
```

should return

```
28, 56, 26, 369, 114
```

*Note that it keeps the previous 26, only last duplicates should be removed*

Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Comment: There isn't a built-in function written for exactly this purpose; you'll have to write a loop (loop backwards would be easiest, checking against prev()) to do this

Comment: The word is "duplicate".

Comment: One time is a typo. 6 times is not knowing how to spell.

Comment: What means END of array ? You can't manipulate "End of array" when you don't know how many entries is that "END" long..

Comment: Can there be other duplicated items within the array?, e.g. `1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2`? Should the result then be `1, 1, 2, 3, 1`?

Comment: This seems like a very strange thing to need to do, where is this coming from?

Comment: There is only one value which should be cut off the end and yes it was not only a typo :/

Comment: @Florija if you have 369 after those 26,26,26 should they be kept or removed ?

Comment: If there is a number which is not 26 after three times 26 then they should not be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE 1 - If you want to remove any duplicates in your array.
Use function `array_unique()`

```
$array = array(28, 56, 26, 369, 114, 26, 26, 26);
$unique_values = array_unique($array);
var_dump($unique_values);
```

[PHP array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

CASE 2 - If you want to remove duplicates only at the end of your array, so if there are duplicates at start they will be kept - its not very pretty code..

```
$arr = array(28, 56, 26, 26, 369, 369,  114, 26, 26, 26, 114);
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
$counts = array_count_values($arr);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($first_element))
        $first_element = $value;
    if($first_element != $value)
        break;
    if($counts[$value] > 1){
        unset($arr[$key]);
        $counts[$value] = $counts[$value] - 1;
    }
}
$arr = array_reverse($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: This would remove *all* dublicates, but I only want to remove dublicates from the end of the array

Comment: #fail - this removes __all__ instances of 26, read the question

Comment: This is the normal way to remove duplicates.. End of array is just the last element of array nothing else..

Comment: @MarkBaker what do you mean that it remove all instances of 26 ? there is 26 on key - 2

Comment: It's the normal way to remove __all__ duplicates, that's not what OP is asking to do

Comment: I mean if the array were `28, 56, 26, 26, 369, 114, 26, 26, 26` then it would give `28, 56, 26, 369, 114`, not `28, 56, 26, 26, 369, 114` which OP is asking for

Comment: OK. I agree with you @MarkBaker . How ever the selected answer provides absolutely same result..

Comment: Gaah - OP seems like he's contradicting himself.... edit your answer so I can retract my downvote - if OP simply wants to remove all duplicates then he should have said so, and this would be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(28, 56, 26, 369, 114, 26, 26, 26);

end($array);
$last = FALSE;
while (current($array) == prev($array)) {
    unset($array[key($array)]);
    $last = TRUE;
}
if ($last) {
    end($array);
    unset($array[key($array)]);
}
var_dump($array);
```